# How to copy built target from build directory to parent directory?

Tags: linux, cmake

my target is built within build directory named example1,but the resource is at data directory outside of build which is ../
I am using this to copy target out of build:

```
file(REMOVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../example1) #remove old one
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/example1 DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../)
```

each single line of them works separately but when I put them together,they don't work,example1 cannot update to the same as the one in the build directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target is named "Example1" say, you should be able to just do:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET Example1 POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                       $<TARGET_FILE:Example1> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/..)
```

However, if this copies your exe from your build tree into your source tree, it may be better to consider keeping your source tree clean by copying the required resources from your source tree into your build tree instead.